# Random IO Error when importing CSV/XLS files into locally installed Carto

Tags: carto

The current situation:

Carto is installed on a on a cloud VM. Everything is working fine except that the programmatical import using the Import API gives inconsistent results. (I am using the NodeJS wrapper for Carto in my GUI, see: [NodeJS Carto](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-nodejs))

I have performed my tests using the same CSV file (with UTF-8 encoding FYI). 
First time the import finished and everything was perfect.
However, right after this, when I wanted to re-import this file, the import API threw an unknown error 99999.

The error message associated with this code was:

> Sorry, something went wrong and we're not sure what. Try
>         uploading your file again, or contact us
>   and we'll try to help you quickly.

I went ahead and checked the logs in the rails console and for my second import attempt - that had the error - I found that there was a line for IO error.
That is now something, but right now I am feeling clueless.

Below I am going to attach two log extracts for your better understanding of this problem. One for the perfect import and another one for the failed import.

Does anybody have a clue as to what might cause this issue and more importantly how a resolution of this problem could be approached?

```
#<CartoDB::Log @values={
:id=>"1fa505f4-e981-4539-b64b-5c91d758b847",
 :type=>"import",
 :user_id=>"48cb4b67-12a6-46e6-a581-d63a77dce9fc",
 :created_at=>2019-05-02 10:45:25 +0000,
 :updated_at=>2019-05-02 10:45:29 +0000,
 :entries=>"2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Running on server test-carto-install with PID: 31783
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: new_importer()
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Fetching datasource public_url metadata for item id public/uploads/07760e1a9295c0475b4e/my_csv.csv
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: File will be downloaded from public/uploads/07760e1a9295c0475b4e/my_csv.csv
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Before importer run
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Starting import for public/uploads/07760e1a9295c0475b4e/my_csv.csv
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Unpacking public/uploads/07760e1a9295c0475b4e/my_csv.csv
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Filename: /tmp/imports/20190502-31783-1vusfu6/my_csv.csv Size (bytes): 238263
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Importing data from /tmp/imports/20190502-31783-1vusfu6/my_csv.csv
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: File-based import load
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Detected encoding UTF-8
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Using database connection with .....
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: ogr2ogr output:          
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: ogr2ogr exit code:       0
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Georeferencing...
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Disabling autovacuum for \"cdb_importer\".\"importer_665a6a426cc711e994516a1e6aacd3aa\"
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Creating the_geom from the_geom column
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: replace empty strings by nulls?
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: string column found,
 replacing
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: geometrifying
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: casting the_geom to geometry
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Converting to 2D point
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: geometrified
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Enabling autovacuum for \"cdb_importer\".\"importer_665a6a426cc711e994516a1e6aacd3aa\"
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Georeferenced
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Finished importing data from /tmp/imports/20190502-31783-1vusfu6/my_csv.csv
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Proceeding to register
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Before renaming from importer_665a6a426cc711e994516a1e6aacd3aa to gence
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Before moving schema 'my_csv_18' from cdb_importer to public
2019-05-02 10:45:28 UTC: Before persisting metadata my_csv_18' data_import_id: 8a91808f-70ce-4eb1-b4a4-c5f0e554950e
2019-05-02 10:45:29 UTC: Table 'gence_18' registered
2019-05-02 10:45:29 UTC: After importer run
2019-05-02 10:45:29 UTC: After dispatch
2019-05-02 10:45:29 UTC: Import finished
"}
```

And the log of the problematic import

```
#<CartoDB::Log @values={:id=>"45ac77a9-5826-4fb4-abf1-a42724c679d9",
 :type=>"import",
 :user_id=>"48cb4b67-12a6-46e6-a581-d63a77dce9fc",
 :created_at=>2019-05-02 10:40:23 +0000,
 :updated_at=>2019-05-02 10:40:28 +0000,
 :entries=>"2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: Running on server test-carto-install with PID: 29138
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: new_importer()
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: Fetching datasource public_url metadata for item id public/uploads/695ed5cbfd66b4edb035/my_csv.csv
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: File will be downloaded from public/uploads/695ed5cbfd66b4edb035/my_csv.csv
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: Before importer run
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: Starting import for public/uploads/695ed5cbfd66b4edb035/my_csv.csv
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: Unpacking public/uploads/695ed5cbfd66b4edb035/my_csv.csv
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: Filename: /tmp/imports/20190502-29138-197g5si/my_csv.csv Size (bytes): 238263
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: Importing data from /tmp/imports/20190502-29138-197g5si/my_csv.csv
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: File-based import load
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: Detected encoding UTF-8
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: Using database connection with ...
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: ogr2ogr output:          
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: ogr2ogr exit code:       0
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: Georeferencing...
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: Disabling autovacuum for \"cdb_importer\".\"importer_b31ef1146cc611e99bf86a1e6aacd3aa\"
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: Creating the_geom from the_geom column
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: replace empty strings by nulls?
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: string column found,
 replacing
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: geometrifying
2019-05-02 10:40:27 UTC: casting the_geom to geometry
2019-05-02 10:40:28 UTC: Converting to 2D point
2019-05-02 10:40:28 UTC: geometrified
2019-05-02 10:40:28 UTC: Enabling autovacuum for \"cdb_importer\".\"importer_b31ef1146cc611e99bf86a1e6aacd3aa\"
2019-05-02 10:40:28 UTC: Georeferenced
2019-05-02 10:40:28 UTC: Finished importing data from /tmp/imports/20190502-29138-197g5si/my_csv.csv
2019-05-02 10:40:28 UTC: Proceeding to register
2019-05-02 10:40:28 UTC: Before renaming from importer_b31ef1146cc611e99bf86a1e6aacd3aa to my_csv
2019-05-02 10:40:28 UTC: Before moving schema 'my_csv_17' from cdb_importer to public
2019-05-02 10:40:28 UTC: Before persisting metadata 'my_csv_17' data_import_id: 62cbd604-d93f-45ff-a796-f1713c920688
2019-05-02 10:40:28 UTC: Exception: Input/output error @ io_write - <STDERR>
2019-05-02 10:40:28 UTC: ERROR!
```

In the stack trace of the IO error I found this:

> "/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:435:in
>   `write'\"

and it made me even more confused as I can't believe that what is working ok at one time does not work the next minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying this small change everything is working perfectly.

In the Carto configuration `(app_config.yml)` there is a section where you can configure Redis settings.
What I did was, I incremented the `write_timeout` attribute by an arbitrary value and amazingly enough that did the trick after a restart.